# Cute limit: $\lim\limits_{x \to 0^{+}}\frac{\sin(x)^x − x^ {\sin(x)}}{\tan(x) ^x − x^{\tan (x)}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

What's the fastest way to calculate the below limit (ideally, without resorting to Taylor expansions)?

$$\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\frac{\sin(x)^x
 − x^ {\sin(x)}}{\tan(x)
^x − x^{\tan (x)}}$$

Comment: Aw dang, Taylor expansion so good though...

Comment: Post a solution with Taylor if you like, i'll accept it if there's no more elementary method.

Comment: What is the context of the question? Why is avoiding series expansions an ideal way? The fastest way is asking [Wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+of+%5B(sin+x)%5Ex-x%5E(sin+x)%5D%2F%5B(tan+x)%5Ex-x%5E(tan+x)%5D+x+-%3E0), which is cheating though: the answer is $\frac{-1}{2}$.

Comment: @Jack : actually expansions works nicely here I just prefer not use more advanced tools if I don't have to.

Comment: Use standard limits to reduce the expression to $$\frac{x\log\sin x -  \sin x\log x} {x\log\tan x -  \tan x\log x} $$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Mean Value Theorem says
$$
\frac{e^x-e^y}{x-y}=e^\xi
$$
for some $\xi$ between $x$ and $y$. Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\sin(x)^x−x^{\sin(x)}}{\tan(x)^x−x^{\tan(x)}}
&=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{x\log(\sin(x))-\sin(x)\log(x)}{x\log(\tan(x))-\tan(x)\log(x)}\tag{1}\\[6pt]
&=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{x\log(x)+x\log\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)-\sin(x)\log(x)}{x\log(x)+x\log\left(\frac{\tan(x)}{x}\right)-\tan(x)\log(x)}\tag{2}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{x-\sin(x)+\frac{x}{\log(x)}\log\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)}{x-\tan(x)+\frac{x}{\log(x)}\log\left(\frac{\tan(x)}{x}\right)}\tag{3}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{x-\sin(x)+\frac{x}{\log(x)}O\!\left(\frac{x-\sin(x)}{x}\right)}{x-\tan(x)+\frac{x}{\log(x)}O\!\left(\frac{x-\tan(x)}{x}\right)}\tag{4}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{x-\sin(x)+O\!\left(\frac{x-\sin(x)}{\log(x)}\right)}{x-\tan(x)+O\!\left(\frac{x-\tan(x)}{\log(x)}\right)}\tag{5}\\[9pt]
&=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{x-\sin(x)}{x-\tan(x)}\tag{6}\\[15pt]
&=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{1-\sec^2(x)}\tag{7}\\[15pt]
&=\lim_{x\to0^+}-\frac{\cos^2(x)}{1+\cos(x)}\tag{8}\\[15pt]
&=-\frac12\tag{9}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: Mean Value Theorem
$(2)$: $\log(ab)=\log(a)+\log(b)$
$(3)$: divide numerator and denominator by $\log(x)$
$(4)$: $\log(1+x)=O(x)$
$(5)$: algebra
$(6)$: $O\!\left({\raise{1.5pt}\frac{u}{\log(x)}}\right)=o(u)$ as $x\to0^+$
$(7)$: L'Hôpital
$(8)$: multiply numerator and denominator by $\frac{\cos^2(x)}{1-\cos(x)}$
$(9)$: evaluate at $x=0$

Comment: I must say that you made a smart move from step $(5)$ to step $(6)$ by using $O(u/\log x) = o(u)$. I on the other hand has to transform the expression obtained in step $(5)$ to a ratio of two limits $A$ and $B$ in my answer. So +1 for that move.

Comment: Please ignore the mention of $A, B$ from previous comment as they do not exist anymore in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

To expand on my comment, I will use the following two limits apart from the standard lmits: $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x - \sin x}{x^{3}} = \frac{1}{6},\,\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x - \tan x}{x^{3}} = -\frac{1}{3}$$ Both the above are easily obtained either via Taylor series or via L'Hospital's Rule.

We have then
\begin{align}
L &= \lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\frac{\sin^{x}x - x^{\sin x}}{\tan^{x}x - x^{\tan x}}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\frac{\exp(\sin x\log x)}{\exp(\tan x\log x)}\cdot\frac{\exp(x\log\sin x - \sin x\log x) - 1}{\exp(x\log\tan x - \tan x\log x) - 1}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\frac{\exp(x\log\sin x - \sin x\log x) - 1}{\exp(x\log\tan x - \tan x\log x) - 1}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\frac{\exp(x\log\sin x - \sin x\log x) - 1}{x\log\sin x - \sin x\log x}\cdot\frac{x\log\sin x - \sin x\log x}{x\log\tan x - \tan x\log x}\notag\\
&\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\cdot\frac{x\log\tan x - \tan x\log x}{\exp(x\log\tan x - \tan x\log x) - 1}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\frac{x\log\sin x - \sin x\log x}{x\log\tan x - \tan x\log x}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\dfrac{(x - \sin x)\log x + x\log\dfrac{\sin x}{x}}{(x - \tan x)\log x + x\log\dfrac{\tan x}{x}}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\frac{x - \sin x}{x - \tan x}\cdot\dfrac{1 - \dfrac{1}{\log x}\dfrac{x}{\sin x - x}\log\dfrac{\sin x}{x}}{1 - \dfrac{1}{\log x}\dfrac{x}{\tan x - x}\log\dfrac{\tan x}{x}}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\frac{x - \sin x}{x - \tan x}\cdot\dfrac{1 - 0\cdot 1}{1 - 0\cdot 1}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\dfrac{\dfrac{x - \sin x}{x^{3}}}{\dfrac{x - \tan x}{x^{3}}}\notag\\
&= -\frac{1}{2}\notag
\end{align}

---

We have used the following standard limits in the derivation above $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\tan x}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\log(1 + x)}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\exp(x) - 1}{x} = 1,\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}x\log x = 0$$ Note that $\sin x\log x = \dfrac{\sin x}{x}\cdot x \log x \to 1\cdot 0 = 0$ as $x \to 0^{+}$ and similarly $\tan x\log x \to 0$. Further $x\log\sin x = x\log x + x\log\dfrac{\sin x}{x} \to 0 + 0\cdot \log 1 = 0$ as $x \to 0^{+}$ and similarly $x\log\tan x \to 0$. Also note that if $t = (\sin x - x)/x$ then $t \to 0$ as $x \to 0^{+}$ and hence $$\frac{x}{\sin x - x}\log\frac{\sin x}{x} = \frac{\log(1 + t)}{t} \to 1$$ and in similar manner $$\frac{x}{\tan x - x}\log\frac{\tan x}{x} \to 1$$

The above is a reasonably fast way (though not as good as the use of Taylor series) to evaluate this cute limit and the real effort is in typing the full solution. The limits mentioned in the beginning of the answer are already famous and play a key role here apart from the standard limits mentioned in the later part of the answer.

Comment: When you first introduce $\log\left(\frac{\sin(x)}x\right)$ and $\log\left(\frac{\tan(x)}x\right)$, they should be $x\log\left(\frac{\sin(x)}x\right)$ and $x\log\left(\frac{\tan(x)}x\right)$. This changes which terms are most significant in the next line. Interesting that the answer comes out the same.

Comment: @robjohn: hats off to you! i would never have caught this myself in such a long derivation. I will fix it in a minute and i think this will make it easier.

Comment: @robjohn: finally fixed it and it did make the question much easier.